# How dangerous are windows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm relatively new to Minecraft.  I've built a few shelters on a few worlds, usually with a high level of success.  However, I've recently been trying to spruce up these shelters and make them nicer-looking.  Part of that is adding windows--both for the nice look and to make it easier to determine the time of day.  So far, I've only added windows in rooms away from my bed, since I am not sure about the safety of glass.

I know that unless they are in pursuit mode, non-spider mobs cannot see a player through glass.  Spiders are not a problem, because they just congregate and make noise on the roof.  The [Glass Page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glass) on the wiki says that "Spider Jockeys can shoot their arrows through glass and cause damage.*[citation needed]*"

So, two main questions:

1. Can Spider Jockeys shoot through glass or not?  Is this intentional or a bug?  Is it something I need to worry about, since they spawn so rarely anyways? (I've only ever seen one)
2. Are there any other perils I need to worry about with regards to using glass as windows or skylights?

Comment: Windows aren't dangerous as long as they're [properly secured](http://superuser.com/questions/14424/how-can-i-make-my-moms-windows-pc-bullet-proof).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spider Jockeys are simply Skeletons riding Spiders, and I know for a fact that Skeletons can't shoot their arrows through glass. If they can, it's most likely a very rarely occurring bug – the fact that there's no citation for that point makes it hard for me to believe. It's not something you need to worry about. (Also, there's nothing on the [Spider Jockey page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spider_Jockey) about being able to shoot through glass.)

Glass is just as good as any other block when it comes to safety. The only thing you might worry about is if a Creeper were to explode near your windows, the glass would absorb less "blast damage" and more of your house may get destroyed, as glass has a very low [blast resistance rating](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion#Blast_Resistance).

Comment: But a Creeper wouldn't explode unless it was pursuing either me or another player, correct?  If a Creeper walks up to the windows where I am looking at it, it cannot see me, and thus will not explode, right?

Comment: Yeah, it won't explode. Glass still acts as a solid block to mobs. I was only referring to if he was stalking you around the outside of your house.

Comment: One disadvantage of windows is that they can be [terrifying](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2011/032/e/a/window_creeper_by_xaldin_iii-d38k30y.png).

Comment: @fredley: This is why all my abodes are either underground or *over* ground. If I look out my window I want to see rock, or a creeper falling to his death. There is no in between.

Comment: Heh, I remember one time when I mined one block out of my wall at head height, and there was a creeper literally two blocks away on the other side of the window, looking RIGHT at me. I put the glass in in a hurry, let me tell you.